# Apache HTTP Server+Tomcat: Which file generates mod_jk.conf, how to modify generated stuff, and how does httpd reach it?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, http, xampp, httpd.conf

I'm using XAMPP with Apache HTTP Server and Tomcat Add-On installed.
There's a default mod_jk.conf which is generated by Tomcat when starting it.

1. But which file generates this mod_jk.conf file?
2. How can I modify default values? By default, it looks like this: [pastebin - mod_jk.conf](http://pastebin.com/UnFdSaBx).
3. How does Apache HTTP Server reach this file? I can't see any reference to this file when looking into httpd.conf.
4. When I put a VirtualHost in my httpd.conf file, and I put the line `JkMount /* ajp13` into it, Apache HTTP Server service can't start (causes a 7024 event id error in Event Viewer (with error code 1, but nothing specific), but puts no error messages into `error.log`. The VirtualHost looks like this: [pastebin - VirtualHost + JkMount](http://pastebin.com/SFauzvdP). This way Apache HTTP Server can not start. If I comment out the line `JkMount /* ajp13`, it starts without a problem.
5. BUT if I put the following line, which is the same as in mod_jk.conf, before the mentioned VirtualHost again, the service can start!

   ```
   <IfModule !mod_jk.c>
       LoadModule jk_module "C:/xampp/tomcat/xampp/apache/modules/mod_jk.so"
   </IfModule>
   ```

Why do I have to put this line in again?

Why does that happen, that the `http://localhost/example` does work, so this query is redirected to AJP13, but I have to put the LoadModule line in again in another file?

EDIT: I don't have a clue why, I surely modified something, but now /example doesn't work either... And the config above gives a 500 Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 1):

1. If not present. It's generated by mod_jk (tomcat module for apache - called also jakarta via Apache which runs Tomcat https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/mod_jk-howto.html#s81 )
2. Using text editor
3. Apache calls module mod_jk which is the tomcat itself
4. Configure workers in Tomcat configuration file called workers.properties
5. as in point # 4

Answer (score 1):

3. you'll find an "Include *.conf" in your Apache configuration.  If your mod_jk.conf is at the right place, Apache will read it.

Answer (score 0):

I have to warn that I'm not familiar with XAMPP.

1. You can trace from the script that starting Tomcat (`startup.bat`, maybe)
2. Try to start Apache before starting Tomcat. Another workaround is edit and mark it as read-only.
3. Insert a `Include` directive in the Apache configuration file, something like this:

   Include /tomcat/conf/mod_jk.conf

4 + 5. You haven't included `mod_jk.conf`, so the `mod_jk.so` wasn't load, therefore, Apache cannot understand the `JkMount` option.

> EDIT: I don't have a clue why, I surely modified something, but now
>   /example doesn't work either... And the config above gives a 500
>   Internal Server Error... :S

Take a look at Apache error log, it will tell you more details.

Comment: 1.) I couldn't find the answer when investigating these batch files. 2.) I really hope this was a joke... :D this means you didn't understand the question... this file is generated every time Tomcat starts!!! I think I wrote it clearly: "There's a default mod_jk.conf which is generated by Tomcat when starting it." 3.) I asked how Apache can reach this file when there are no Include parts related to mod_jk.conf in httpd.conf...but localhost/example does work, which is setup in the mentioned file. 4-5.) As I said, Apache loads this file somehow automatically, because localhost/example works...

Comment: Sorry, but this answer would desire a vote-down, but I can't and wouldn't vote down your answer, because you tried to help at least...

Comment: Please post the `startup.bat`, `server.xml`, and `httpd.conf`?